# Jquery autocomplete suggestions - small font list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Jquery Autocomplete suggestions list font is very bigger ,I want to be small like typing in text box font need.  how to restrict with small fonts in suggestions list ? Please see the below screen and code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Complete in JSP Java</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css" media="all">
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: default;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
</STYLE>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#names").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "searchName.jsp",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { name: request.term},
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var items = data;
                    response(items);
                },
    error: function (error) {
       alert('error: ' + error);
    }
    });
    },
    minLength: 3
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="names" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is defined in:

```
.ui-widget {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

But you may precede it something e.g.

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for example :

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('fontSize', '10px');
```

Information on styling the Autocomplete widget can be found here:

[Theming autocomplete jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#theming)

The `ul` markup following the `ui-autocomplete-input` is the results it generates. By targeting `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu` you should get what you need.